# String pattern finding, Is Regex Applicable to my requirement?

Tags: java, regex, qregexp

I am trying to find some string pattern (`"isempty var0")out of some long String which i am getting while reading a file, i am not sure if Regex Applicable to my requirement?

To be more precise in the expected String pattern `isempty` is a keyword and there would be some java variable next to it after some space.

Input Strings can be something like this:

```
"isempty var0 && v1== 56"
"v2 == 50 || isempty var1"
"Q3 == 100 || (isempty var2)"
"isempty var3"
"is thisnotisempty var4"
```

And expected output is:

```
"isempty var0"
"isempty var1"
"isempty var2"
"isempty var3"
 null
```

> Currently i am trying to find the pattern using String.contains(),
>   String.CharAt(), String.indexOf() methods etc.
>
> Though i am not sure if this can be solved with Regex?? If it can be can someone give some idea, What could be
>   the Regex to find this kind of pattern?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
\bisempty\s+\w+
```

[Online demo.](https://regex101.com/r/pW3zC4/1)

Comment: Thanks it's working. i am new with regex, can you recommend some good tutorial to start with it??

Comment: @shriduttkothari I don't know any tutorials, sorry. I learned regex just by reading the documentation.

Comment: can you share which documentation you followed?

Comment: @shriduttkothari I used [the python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) (python is my language of choice), but you might be better off reading the Java Regex documentation. There are probably a few differences.

Answer (score 1):

Your examples look very much like you are trying to process raw program code.

The short answer is YES you can use a regex pattern to look at a thing and work out if it contains the values you are looking for. Something like `(\w+\s+\w+)` would be a starting point, although it would probably end up more complicated than that.

The long answer is that if you are processing program code you may need to look into using a textural parsing API. A quick search on good with the keywords `java code parser` sourced quite a number. Parsers understand the structure of your text where as regex can only test and examine it. So a parser can help when you need to validate the structure of the code as well as identify particular syntax structures such as your `isempty x` construct.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use regex to do this (in many ways). One option is `replaceAll`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String s1 = "isempty var0 && v1== 56";
    String s2 = "isempty var3";
    String s3 = "is thisnotisempty var4";
    String s4 = "is thisnotisempty 4var4"; // returns empty string. Java variable names cannot start with a number.
    String s5 = "Q3 == 100 || (isempty var2)";
    String s6 = "isempty var3";

    System.out.println(s1.replaceAll(".*\\b(isempty\\b\\s+(?!\\d+)[a-zA-z0-9_]+).*|.*", "$1"));
    System.out.println(s2.replaceAll(".*\\b(isempty\\b\\s+(?!\\d+)[a-zA-z0-9_]+).*|.*", "$1"));
    System.out.println(s3.replaceAll(".*\\b(isempty\\b\\s+(?!\\d+)[a-zA-z0-9_]+).*|.*", "$1"));
    System.out.println(s4.replaceAll(".*\\b(isempty\\b\\s+(?!\\d+)[a-zA-z0-9_]+).*|.*", "$1"));
    System.out.println(s5.replaceAll(".*\\b(isempty\\b\\s+(?!\\d+)[a-zA-z0-9_]+).*|.*", "$1"));
    System.out.println(s6.replaceAll(".*\\b(isempty\\b\\s+(?!\\d+)[a-zA-z0-9_]+).*|.*", "$1"));
}
```

O/P :

```
isempty var0
isempty var3


isempty var2
isempty var3
```

PS : Note that you won't get `null` here (when the string doesn't "have" `isempty someVar`, instead you will get empty String.